# Convert column of text to number using VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I am looking to sort and group a workbook based on 1 column. That column is pulled from external software so it's imported in text.

I've attempted using:

```
Sub Whatever()

With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    .Value = Evaluate(.Address & "*1")
End With
End Sub
```

However, it converts all columns to number when I just need the column P (actually P2 thru whatever, due to a column label) converted. Thoughts on how to just convert 1 column?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Application.Max(2, Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row)
    With Range("P2:P" & lastrow)
        .NumberFormat = "0"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Simoco. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the range value to itself, it'll convert the text to numbers for you.  ie

```
Columns("P").Value = Columns("P").Value
```